# Zend - resizing image after upload

Tags: php, image, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I need to resize the users' avatars to be 150x150 px after they upload. The thing is, my employer wants me to not use a PHP library, but a Zend one, and I couldn't find any. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: what did you try already?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method in zf2. But you can [write filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.filter.writing-filters.html) that will wrap this behavior:

take `Zend\Filter\File\Rename.php` as an example and alter it to use your preferences.

I would probably use [php-imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) commands like:

```
$imagick = new \Imagick($path);
$imagick->resizeImage(217, 0, $imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
$imagick->writeImage($thumbPath);
$imagick->clear();
```